# React Router v1.5.2 is not routing to component

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently building a reactjs application that uses routing. The react router version I am using is v5.1.2. The `WelcomeVisitor` component renders just fine but when navigation to the `Thankyou` component it does not render it. I put logs inside the class and they were never called. I tried to use `withRouter` too but still got the same results.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "reactjs-webpack-starter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.11.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
        "react-router": "^5.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
        "webp-loader": "^0.5.0",
        "webpack": "^4.41.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "../css/App.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import WelcomeVisitor from '../components/WelcomeVisitor'
import ThankYou from '../components/ThankYou'



export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/thankyou" compoenent={ThankYou}/>
          <Route exact path="/welcome" component={WelcomeVisitor}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

WelcomeVisitor.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "../css/WelcomeScreen.css"
import Trapezoid from '../components/Trapezoid'
import GuestName from '../components/GuestName'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'

export default function WelcomeVisitor(){
    return (
        <div className="parentView">
            <Trapezoid />
            <GuestName guestName="Quinton Thompson"/>
            <Logo />
        </div>
    )
}
```

ThankYou.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "../css/ThankYou.css"

export default function ThankYou(){
    console.log("Inside Thank You Component")
    return(
        <div className="parentView">
            <h1 className="test">Hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `compoenent={ThankYou}/>` should be `component={ThankYou}/>`

Comment: Wow. Been a long day. haha. Thank you @PeterB